# Setting unordered_map as value for unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So I am trying to set an unordered_map as value for another unordered_map.
Now I have the problem that I am not able to put values into the second unordered_map.
My code looks like this.

```
  std::string postCode;
  std::string[] postCodeSource = new std::string{1111,2222,3333,4444};
  std::unordered_map<std::string,unordered_map<int,Foo*>*> data;
  int k1=1234;//can be any number
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    postCode = postCodeSource[i]
    if(data[postCode]==NULL) {
      data[postCode]=new std::unordered_map<int,Foo*>();
    }
    data[postCode]->at(int(k1)) = new Foo(postCodeSource[i]);
  }
```

classes:

```
class Foo{
  public:
  Foo();
  Foo(std::string postCode);
  std::string firstName,Customername,postCode;
}
```

`Foo(std::string postCode);` is a simple copy constructor.

Now when I reach `data[lastPlz.getString()]->at(int(k1.customer)) = new Foo(&k1);` I get an out of range exception from unordered_map which makes sense since there is no object at k1.customer yet!
Before I changed the code I created and filled a pointer looking like that.

```
std::unordered_map<int,Foo*> kdnrMap
kdnrMap[k1.customer] = new Foo(&k1);
```

and later on, I added **kdnrMap** to **data**.
That won't work anymore the way I intended since this method would need a completely filled **kdnrMap** before I can add it to **data** which I can't do anymore.

So I am looking for help to get **kdnrMap** filled I've tried pretty much anything I could think of for now.

Comment: There is so much code that is missing here.  A [MCVE] would probably make this simple to solve.

Comment: Okay what would you like to have added to make it more understandable?
This is pretty much the whole function I have problems with.

Comment: `Foo`, `Foo2`; a minimal example that actually compiles.  We could probably tease your problem out of your text description, but that is needlessly complicated and ambiguous.  Just write some simple code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please note that `operator[]` is quite expensive, you better use it only once unless it is really necessary to use it multiple times. You as your map seems to have ownership of the data you better use smart pointers.

Comment: Btw why do you need to store inner map as a pointer? Just to make your code more complicated and error prone?

Comment: is "postCode" the same as "lastPlz.getString()"? And how is postCode initialized?

Comment: And, why do you store `Foo` in the inner map as a pointer? Why not simply `std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unordered_map<int,Foo>> data;`?

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with dynamic memory allocation? Java background? You make your life much more complicated than necessary using `new` everywhere

Comment: @Slava yes, java broke me a bit that way, also I always think about pointers being faster than "actual" objects.
The map is for receiving, storing and printing the data so I need as fast access as I can get

Comment: Then you are making it not only more complicated but a bit slower as another unnecessary indirection would be involved. Guess where `std::unordered_map` stores its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to store the inner map as a pointer. Just let the outer map own the inner one like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,
   std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>>> data;
data[postCode][int(k1.Kundennr)] = new Foo(&k1);
```

I advise against using raw pointers here, since there is a high risk of leaking memory if you replace a value in the inner map. Using `std::unique_ptr` makes it so much simpler to deal with pointers.

Your exception probably happens because `unordered_map::at` requires the value to contain the key you are asking for, in order to retrieve the reference to the value it is mapping. If you use `operator[]` instead like in my example, the map will create an entry if the key is not found.

If you still insist on having the outer map's values to be pointers to the inner map, then you can add elements like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Foo*> &inner = *data[postCode];
inner[int(k1.Kundennr)] = new Foo(&k1);
```

or

```
data[postCode]->operator[](int(k1.Kundennr)) = new Foo(&k1);
```

Comment: Thanks! ->operator[] did exactly what I was looking for.
I might be far of with that but I used the inner map as a pointer because I thougth it to be faster.
I am not sure if I should use smart pointers, I am working on a programm that's older than 20 years and we have a LOT of raw pointers, I was teached not to mix those two

Comment: Your thought is wrong, if you are lucky it would be not slower

Comment: If you can't use smart pointers, then be aware that `data[postCode][0] = new Foo()` may leak memory if you don't check if a previous entry exists for the same key. All in all, `unordered_map` exists since C++11, so if you are including a modern feature into old code, you might as well do it properly.

Comment: All the Data comes from a Database postCode is (obviously) not unique.
But the second iterator is a unique customerID so the possibillity if this just beeing overridden is very small to non existent.
Still thanks for the advise!

Comment: @Slava since my code runs as intended now I'm going to make some performance tests tomorrow and check if using object's isn't faster. 
Thanks for your advice and I am actually pretty interested in the results!

Comment: @alovaros I doubt you can reliable test the difference for additional indirection, anyway `std::unordered_map` stpores its values in dynamically allocated memory so you do not win anything, that's for sure.

Comment: Chances are it won't make much difference. Unordered maps make allocations when resizing the hash table and adding new nodes anyway. However, the code is much simpler and easier to maintain.